# Why does my AngularJS home page not load when linked from itself

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ngroute

This is my home-index.js file

```
var homeIndexModule = angular.module("homeIndex", ["ngRoute"]);

homeIndexModule.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/templates/topicsView.html",
        controller: topicsController
    })
    .when("/newmessage", {
        templateUrl: "/templates/newTopicView.html",
        controller: newTopicController
    })
    .when("/message/:id", {
        templateUrl: "/templates/singleTopicView.html",
        controller: singleTopicController
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

}]);
```

I have a base html page which links to four pages.

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Messages", "MyMessages", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

When the site loads it goes to "http:/localhost:51264/#/", which loads the home page and everything works fine (the "/templates/topicsView.html" page).  But if (from that page) I click the Home link again, it goes to "http://localhost:51264/#", without the slash and the topicsView.html isn't loaded.  If I put the slash back it loads fine.

If I access the home page from the contacts page it properly loads "http:/localhost:51264/#/"

if "/#/" is the right spot for the homepage that's fine, as long as I could ensure if someone accesses "/#" it redirects there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074401/route-to-different-viewuse-html-actionlink-and-ng-view-in-view-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Please add `<base>` tag in your `<head>` tag of page

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  //Note:- But when you go live replace above line by "sub-context" of your Application URL
  //e.g Your application is running on www.example.com/testApp/ 
  //then change above <base> tag to <base href="/testApp/">
  ...
</head>
```

Additional,
if you want to get rid of '#' from URL then please Use following code

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {        

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });  
}])
```

Link for reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Hope this solution help you to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe part 1 & 2 of my answer [`HERE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958874/generate-static-seo-pages-for-angularjs-spring-mvc-website/38095249#38095249) guide you to handle routes and ...

**1) Removing `#` from url**

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/any_route', {
        templateUrl: 'view.html',
        controller: 'Controller'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

}]);
```

---

**2) Review your MVC Routing**

Till now maybe you had one HomeController for returning `index.cshtml` and booting up your Angular App.
After removing `#` from Angular routing, you have to set `MapRoute` for all of your routes.
Because in this situation the first time you try to visit routes like `www.site.com/any_route` Angular App not loaded yet so it tries to get page from MVC Routing. But after that `$routeProvider` do its duties.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "any_route",
    url: "any_route",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have several idea's

- > Manually configure route for empty location

The different is the last slash in URL. When I click "#/" for the first time, angular redirect the URL to #//, and load ng-view. when I click it second time, because the current URL is #//, it's not equal to the URL in the config("#/") I clicked, so Angular triggers the location change method and reloads the ng-view, in addition Angular redirects the URL to #// again. next time I click the URL, angular does the same thing again.

In this case we needs to add another one configuration for empty URL, like

```
$routeProvider.when("", {
        templateUrl: "/templates/topicsView.html",
        controller: topicsController
    })
```

Now if this URL is empty or with a slash, then it's will be going to the proper location.

- > You go to force reload the URL

**Otherwise:** you should use [$route.reload()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route#reload) to force the reload. But it's make to load the page

And please take a look at this [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267284/angularjs-refresh-when-clicked-on-link-with-actual-url)

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested it myself but I think this change will work:

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "#/", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Messages", "MyMessages", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Only change in above code is `"Index"` became `"#/"`, so that your angular route can work properly.